# What is the difference between XmlTextWriter and XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter, xmltextwriter

I am looking at these these two classes in C#: `XmlTextWriter` and `XmlWriter`.
Can anyone explain the difference and tell me where to use which?

Comment: Well, first off, you can't instantiate `XmlWriter`.

Comment: @BoltClock Hm, technically yes, but it has a static `Create()` method which creates an instance. Doesn't that count?

Comment: @Marcel: You can only create an instance of a subclass. You can't do `new XmlWriter` because it's abstract.

Comment: @BoltClock I just called `XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)` right now and it gives me an `XmlWriter`. It's also described exactly to do so in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Marcel: What does `GetType()` on that instance return?

Comment: @BoltClock In my case, it's a `XmlWellFormedWriter`. You get the point.

Answer (score 32):

`XmlWriter` is an abstract class.
`XmlTextWriter` is a specific implementation of `XmlWriter`.

You should always call `XmlWriter.Create`.

MSDN says:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 release, the recommended practice is
>   to create XmlWriter instances using the XmlWriter.Create method and
>   the XmlWriterSettings class. This allows you to take full advantage of
>   all the new features introduced in this release. For more information,
>   see [Creating XML Writers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kkz7cs0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: "You should always call XmlWriter.Create" why do you make this assertion ?

Comment: @Steve: Because Microsoft does.

Comment: Too bad `XmlWriter` and `XmlWriterSettings` miss a `QuoteChar` property which `XmlTextWriter` has, rendering them useless if you require (for whatever reasons) 'single-quoted' attributes instead of the "double-quoted" ones.