# How to modify the default indent value when creating an XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have been looking at different methods for creating an XML document using: `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` and `XmlWriter`. It seems like I have to use `XmlWriterSettings` along with `XmlWriter` in order to specify the `Indent` and `IndentChars`.

This [MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create?view=netframework-4.8) specifies that the default `IndentChars` value is *Two spaces*.

**My question:** Is it possible to save an XML file using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` where I can specify the indent value for the saved XML file?

If it is possible to do so without using `XmlWriter`, can someone provide an example or documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Sorry, I didn't read clearly your question. No, it is not possible.
If you want to specify IdentChars, you should create `XmlTextWriter`

```
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // your logic 


    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter("filename.xml")) {
        writer.Indentation = 1;
        writer.IndentChar = ' ';

        xmlDoc.Save(writer);
    }
```

Comment: And where are you specifying the indent value?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I am looking for a method where I can specify the indent value before saving the file. Using your code would save the file with only two spaces as the indent value. How can I save the file with four spaces as the indent value without using `XmlWriter`?

Comment: @Anton, thank you for changing your answer. I recently read that `XmlTextWriter` isn't the optimal way for changing the IndentChars, they recommend using `XmlWriter`. Here is a link to the source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6899460/7556093

Comment: However, I will accept your answer as the correct answer unless someone knows a solution within the day.

Comment: @Elias Wick Agreed.